# Does updating a user property in Firebase Analytics update the user property value against events sent prior to the update?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

We're using Firebase Analytics for an app, and looking to add user properties to the event tracking we’re currently using. However, we were considering using user properties for values which can change during the session—a user could have multiple 'profiles' in the app, and switch between them in the course of a session, which would means that we'd want certain properties to apply only to actions done when the user was logged into a particular 'profile'. Were we to set a user property to one value on user login, then update it after the user switched 'profile', would the new user property value be *retrospectively applied to all previously-gathered event values*, or would the values be associated with whatever the user property value was *at the time the events were sent*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are asking in context of BigQuery (and UI should follow BigQuery 'way of thinking') If you take a look at [BigQuery export schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en) then you can see that every event has associated user properties. After user does something, their event is persisted with associated user property at the time. After you change user property, **new events will have new user property associated, but old events will still have old user property**. User property is not retroactively updated in old events.